# Mongoose/Mongodb Aggregate - group and average multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a Post model with 2 fields : date and rating. How would I go about getting an average aggregate rating for each date? So group by date first and then average the rating across all posts for that date. I need to do this within mongoose but their docs are so difficult to understand.

```
const PostSchema = new Schema({
    date: {
      type: String,
      default: getToday() //this is just a new Date() formatted
    },
    rating: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  }, 
)
```

This gives me the average across all dates but I can't figure out how to filter it by date:

```
Post.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: null, avgRating: { $avg: '$rating' }}}
  ])
  .then(function (res) {
    console.log(res[0]["avgRating"]); 
  })
```

Comment: you need to use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) accumulator, something like
 `{$group: { "_id"  : "$date" , "date_average" : { "$avg" : "$rating" }}}`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  Post.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$date", avgRating: { $avg: '$rating' }}}
  ]).
  then(function (res) {
    console.log(res); 
  })
```

Output:

```
[
  { _id: 'Aug 18, 2021', avgRating: 3.0212234706616727 },
  { _id: 'Aug 19, 2021', avgRating: 2.9680319680319682 },
  { _id: 'Aug 20, 2021', avgRating: 3.023976023976024 },
  { _id: 'Aug 17, 2021', avgRating: 2.9600665557404326 },
  { _id: 'Aug 21, 2021', avgRating: 3.072661217075386 }
]
```

BUT it would be great if I could somehow filter this based on other factors. For example, each post has an author (reference to User model). How would I go about filtering based on the author's country.name or gender?

User model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
birthday: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
},
gender:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
country:{
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    flag: {
        type: String,
        // default: "/images/flags/US.png"
    }
},
avatar: AvatarSchema,
displayName: String,
bio: String,
coverColor: {
    type: String,
    default: "#343a40"
},
posts: [ 
    {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post" 
    }
],
comments: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }
],
postedToday: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
todaysPost: {
    type: String
}
})
```

Something like this

```
    Post.aggregate([
    {$match: {"date": today}},
    {$group: {_id: {"country": "$author.country.name"}, avgRating: {$avg: "$rating"}}}
]).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: not sure if i should ask this in a separate post?