# Populating in Mongodb Aggregating

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, populate

I just asked a related question here:
[Mongoose/Mongodb Aggregate - group and average multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875221/mongoose-mongodb-aggregate-group-and-average-multiple-fields/68875802#68875802)

I'm trying to use Model.aggregate() to find the average rating of all posts by date and then by some author's subdocument like country.name or gender. Having trouble with this though. I know for the first stage I just need to use $match for the date and I think I need to use $lookup to "populate" the author field but not sure how to implement this.

This works for finding an average rating for all posts by date:

```
  Post.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$date", avgRating: { $avg: '$rating' }}}
  ]).
  then(function (res) {
    console.log(res); 
  })
```

And this is basically what I want to do but it doesn't work:

```
Post.aggregate([
    {$match: {"date": today}},
    {$group: {_id: {"country": "$author.country.name"}, avgRating: {$avg: "$rating"}}}
]).then(function(res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

User model:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
},
birthday: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
},
gender:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
country:{
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    flag: {
        type: String,
        // default: "/images/flags/US.png"
    }
},
avatar: AvatarSchema,
displayName: String,
bio: String,
coverColor: {
    type: String,
    default: "#343a40"
},
posts: [ 
    {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post" 
    }
],
comments: [
    {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }
],
postedToday: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},
todaysPost: {
    type: String
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an aggregation after you fetched the data from the MongoDB. Your `Query will look a bit like this:

```
modelName.aggregate([{
                                $unwind: ''//if Needed
                            }, {
                                $group: {
                                    _id: {"country":"$author.country.name"},
                                    avgRating: {
                                        $avg: '$rating'
                                    }
                            }])
        .exec(function(err, transactions) {
            // ERRORHANDLING
            // CallsBacks                
            modelName.populate(columnName, {path: '_id'}, function(err, populatedModel) {
                // Your populated columnName  inside TaleName
            });
        });
```

Comment: what would columnName be in this case? i'm trying to populate the "author" field, which in itself has a {country: name, flag} field